# How to remove 301 status code from phone cache

Tags: android, http

I'm developing an Android application. The API developer accidently added 301 redirects, but the url didn't change. Now when I do a call, ClientHttpRequest/-Response always return 301 as status code instead of the correct one that occurs afterwards. So my validity check fails.

How to get rid of the 301 status? There seems to be a cache. So I tried deleting browser cache, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of the HttpConnection.

When I use HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory instead of SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the cache then it just works.